# Запятая перед предлогом "в сравнении"

Tags: запятые, предлоги

"...валовое производство зерна в нынешнем году может вырасти почти на 2,5 млн тонн (?) в сравнении с прошлым годом".
Нужна ли запятая перед предлогом "в сравнении" в данном случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**В СРАВНЕНИИ / ПО СРАВНЕНИЮ С (кем, чем)**, *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_793)

> Обороты, присоединяемые предлогами «в сравнении с», «по сравнению с», могут обособляться.
>
> *Втайне от себя он понимал, что эти люди очень образованны и что он, **в сравнении с** ними, невежда.* М. Горький, Жизнь Клима Самгина. *Поп, телега и лошадки **в сравнении с** Мишей казались игрушечными.* В. Шишков, Емельян Пугачев.

В Вашем предложении **обособление не требуется**, так как оборот с предлогом находится в конце предложения, не разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое, а также интонационно не выделяется.

О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, можно посмотреть [**здесь**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1).

Comment: Я бы тоже не стала ставить запятую. Вот похожие предложения. 1. _Кафе и столовые нарастили средний чек на 45%, до 421 руб., по сравнению с показателями прошлой недели и **на 4% в сравнении с прошлым годом.**_ 2. _Урожайность в регионе снизилась **на 30-40% в сравнении с прошлым годом,** особенно для сорта гевюртцтраминер._